# phonegap file transfer not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap 3.5 and I use the code for file transfer to a remote server

```
   function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();

        alert(typeof FileUploadOptions === "undefined");
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
  options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
   };
     options.chunkedMode = false;
        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
alert("object is " + options.fileName);

 alert(typeof FileTransfer === "undefined");
        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("myserver url "), win, fail, options);
    }
```

file transfer is undefined howver I installed both plugins for file and filetransfer

Comment: Maybe try to remove the platforms/android folder, plugins folder and re-add the platform and re-install the plugin. When you install plugins, the file plugins/android.json is updated and multiple times I've seen it corrupted.

Comment: I did that , the same error

Comment: Do the plugins appear correctly if you run `cordova plugins ls`? How are you running your project? (using cli or eclipse)

Comment: yes ,it appears ,I am using the cli